# Can I exclude/ignore files from Multi-Device Hybrid App build? (In order to prevent EBUSY error when building)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm getting this error when building my Multi-Device Hybrid App.

> EXEC : error : EBUSY, resource busy or locked 'C:\path\to\project\bld\Debug\www\.svn\wc.db'

*Suspected cause:*

From what I can gather, when the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Visual Studio extension builds the app it seems to grab all files in the project directory (except for some specific files/folders e.g. bld/bin directories and the .jsproj file) and add them to the package. That's ok, but not ideal, it really should only be grabbing the files in the VS project. The problem I'm experiencing is becuase it's grabbing my SVN .db file and adding it to the package, TortoiseSVN status cache then picks up this file and locks it - resulting in my error.

This is my specific issue, but I believe others could experience similar issues if they have any other files in the directory that they don't want included in the app bundle. I'd suggest it could be fixed by somehow setting excluded files/folders from the build or by the build script not grabbing everything, only those files included in the visual studio project. I'm not sure how to request that, so hopefully the developers will see this post...

**So, my question is:** Does anyone know of any way to tell the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Visual Studio extension build process (or vs-mda\vs-cli) to ignore certain files or folders?

Or, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to make SVN and this VS extension play nice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Visual Studio includes all the files under project directory except bin\bld folder. Currently only simple workaround would be to keep the files which you want to be excluded from package outside project directory. You can add the file to solution explorer by using **Add --> Existing Item --> Add as link** in case you want the file to appear in solution explorer but not included for build or packaging.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Adding as a link doesn't help in the case of SVN (or any other source control) adding its own folder. What I have done, however, is to add a sub folder to the SVN repo and put the project in that. While it's not quite the _ideal_ solution, it works. So now the _.svn_ folder is in the parent/root (trunk) folder and the project file itself (and associated app files) are in a sub-folder. That way SVN can operate as normal and I don't have to worry about its files being pulled into the app package.

Answer (score 0):

it seems folder with test as its name will be considered differently, and it will be excluded from package.